# Formatting a number in ios

Tags: ios, padding, number-formatting

I am trying to find a solution to add zeros in the beginning of the number as per the total input provided.

Example:
Number = 100
Total Number of digits = 3

The kind of format i will like to have is 001,002,003 and so on.

Thanks

I found out the solution for the same. Posting it below:

```
 while (totalNumCopy) {
        totalNumCopy = totalNumCopy/10;
        noOfDigits++;
    }

    NSMutableString *thumbName = nil;
    if(noOfDigits > 0)
    {
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setFormatWidth:noOfDigits];
        [formatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
        [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
        NSString *stringNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1]];
        thumbName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PageThumb%@.png",stringNumber];
        [formatter release];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

the basic string formatter is like this:

```
NSLog(@"%03d, %03d, %03d", 1, 2, 3);
```

the result would be:

```
001, 002, 003
```

maybe it helps on you.

Comment: The total number counted is dynamic. Its value is generated at runtime. So it can even have 4 digits also. I know this it can be done using the NSNumberFormatter. Just need some help on it that how to do it.

Comment: what result do you expect exactly? please, re-define your question then.

Comment: I did fount out the solution for the same please check above. Thanks anyways for the help

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *myNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03d", number];
```

i think the above code will help you